# Alternative for onclick window.location

Tags: javascript, redirect

I have a button:

```
<input class="formatButton verInfo2"  type="button" value="Aceptar" id="btnAceptar" />
```

That when clicked calls a whole bunch of fun-ctions that in turn call PHP etc, the problem is that all this magic happens on another page, this button is a mere trigger. I wanted to load such other page when the button is clicked and onclick=window.location was doing the job, expect that when used like this:

```
<input class="formatButton verInfo2"  type="button" value="Aceptar" id="btnAceptar" onclick="window.location='somepage.php';" />
```

It totally ignored the scripts that I have at the end of my document, I specially need it to trigger the last one because it uses the button's id:

```
  <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src = "js/agregarPcLogic.js"></script>
  <script src="js/addLab.js"></script>
```

I figure that such thing happens because it read the code in order and once the button is pressed and it loads the other page it just ignores the rest, so I figure that adding such scripts somewhere before could fix that but I think it would look bulky, so my question is, is there any other method or technique I could use to load a page?

Or is the best solution?

```
<input class="formatButton verInfo2"  type="button" value="Aceptar" id="btnAceptar" 
  <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src = "js/agregarPcLogic.js"></script>
  <script src="js/addLab.js"></script>
  onclick="window.location='somepage.php';" />
```

Thanks alot in advance for your kind words of wisdom.

Answer (score 0):

Decided to just add another script with:

```
$("id of button").click(function(){
  window.location.href='link to page .php';
})
```